# Python: Regular expression to extract text between any two tags in a html

Tags: python, html, regex

I tried using `"<.+>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/?.+>"` on a HTML file. The following is the Python code I used

```
import re

def recursiveExtractor(content):
    re1='(<.+>\s*(.+?)\s*<\/?.+>)'
    m = re.findall(re1,content)
    if m:
        for (id,item) in enumerate(m):
            text=m[id][1]
            if text:print text,"\n"

f = """
<div class='a'>
      <div class='b'>
        <div class='c'>
            <button>text1</button>
            <div class='d'>text2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
"""
recursiveExtractor(f)
```

But it skips some text since HTML is nested and regex restarts search from the end of the matched part.

For the above input,
the output is

```
<div class='b'>

<div class='d'>text2</div>

</div>
```

But the expected Output is:

```
text1

text2
```

Edit:
I read that HTML is not a regular language and hence cant be parsed.From what I understand, it is not possible to parse  .*  (ie with same closing tags). 
But what I need would be text between any tags, for instance  text1  text2  text3  So I am fine with a list of "text1","text2","text3"

Comment: Obligatory link to warn again parsing HTML with regex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3923281

Comment: @ajcr I dont need to parse html structure. From what I understand, it is not possible to parse <div> .* </div> (ie with same closing tags).
 But what I need would be text between any tags, 
for instance <div> text1 <span> text2 </span> text3 </div> 
So I am fine with a list of "text1","text2","text3"

Comment: Ah OK - you might be able to get away with using regex in this more limited way then. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just doing this:

```
import re

f = """
<div class='a'>
      <div class='b'>
        <div class='c'>
            <button>text1</button>
            <div class='d'>text2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
"""
x = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', f)  # you can also use re.sub('<[A-Za-z\/][^>]*>', '', f)

print '\n'.join(x.split())
```

This will have the following output:

```
text1
text2
```

Comment: Ah, Nice way to approach it. Just what I needed, Thanks